# About ROS_RMPT_SLAM package compiling issue

Tags: compatibility, mobile-robot-toolkit

While doing `catkin_make ROS_MRPT_SLAM`, I got following error

```
In file included from /usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CFileGZInputStream.h:12:0,
                 from /home/ian/catkin_ws/src/mrpt_slam/mrpt_ekf_slam_2d/include/mrpt_ekf_slam_2d/mrpt_ekf_slam_2d.h:11,
                 from /home/ian/catkin_ws/src/mrpt_slam/mrpt_ekf_slam_2d/src/mrpt_ekf_slam_2d.cpp:7:
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h: In member function ‘void mrpt::utils::CStream::WriteVariant(T)’:
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:313:15: error: use of ‘auto’ in lambda parameter declaration only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
   t.match([&](auto& o) { this->WriteObject(o); });
               ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h: In lambda function:
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:313:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘mrpt::utils::CStream::WriteObject(int&)’
   t.match([&](auto& o) { this->WriteObject(o); });
```

I guess it's compatibility matter or something because there were missing header files and so on.

This is the `ROS_PACKAGE` wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/mrpt_slam

And I just followed instruction from official MRPT website.

If the developer or anyone who is familiar with `mrpt toolkit` sees this question, may I get some advice about these errors?

By the way, I installed `mrpt toolkit` using the following website's instruction: http://www.mrpt.org/MRPT_in_GNU/Linux_repositories.

Comment: Still wonder why I can't find a header file (threads.h).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the main author of MRPT and of part of the ROS packages.

Sorry for the mess, but you found us in the transition between the mrpt series 1.5.* and a new mayor rewrite based on C++14 which currently is published in git as mrpt 1.9.9 and eventually will be released as 2.0.0.

This transition must be propagated to the ros nodes, but so far we have upgraded [mrpt_navigation](https://github.com/mrpt-ros-pkg/mrpt_navigation) only, mrpt_slam is in the to-do list.

So: a solution is to install an mrpt version of the 1.5.* series, and to build the ros packages from sources, paying attention to checking out the branches named `compat-mrpt-1.5`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Mrpt version of the 1.5.* series means, I guess, I need to compile/install it manually. Am I right? Because when I checked packages, there were only 1.3 version and 1.9 version. One more thing, is this https://github.com/MRPT/mrpt mrpt's main git address? Thank you a lot brother.

Comment: Yes, for now, download and build manually the latest 1.5.* release. I'm working on a [PPA for the mrpt-1.5 series](https://launchpad.net/~joseluisblancoc/+archive/ubuntu/mrpt-1.5) but it's not working properly yet...

Comment: Is 1.9.* release next target after repo?

Comment: I tried with 1.5.3 version, and I guess it has compatibility issue too. Here is errors that I got. `error: ‘mrpt::obs::CSensoryFrame::Ptr’ has not been declared
   CSensoryFrame::Ptr _sf, CObservationOdometry::Ptr _odometry)`                I guess, I will wait for next release.

Comment: Hi, Please, open an issue ticket in the GitHub repo and we'll discuss it there. Thanks.